# Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs, postcss, autoprefixer

My gruntfile was working as expected until I added in postcss and autprefixer. I follwed the guide at https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer. However I am getting the dreaded:

```
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: undefined is not a function
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

My gruntfile looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
uglify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
        "js/wd.min.js" : [
            "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.core.min.js",
            "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js",
            "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js",
            "node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.equalizer.min.js",
            "js/wd.js"
        ]
    },
    options: {
        beautify:true,
        compress:false
    }
  }
},
watch: {
    dist: {
        files: [
            /* JS locations */
            "js/wd.js",

            /* SCSS locations */
            "style/**/*.scss",
        ],
        tasks: [
            "uglify",
            "sass_imports",
            "sass",
            "postcss"
        ]
    }
},
sass: {
    options: {
        loadPath: [
            'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
            require("bourbon").includePaths
        ],
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
            "style/style.css" : [
                "style/style.scss",
            ],
        },
        options: {
            require: "sass-css-importer"
        }
    }
},
sass_imports: {
    dist: {
        src: [
            "style/style.scss"
        ],
        dest: "all.scss"
    }
},
postcss: {
    options: {
        map: true,
        processors: [
            require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'})
        ]
    },
    dist: {
        src: "style/style.css"
    }
}
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-scss-imports');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');

//load watch plugin

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

All solutions I have have come across have referenced a typo somwhere but I can't see it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

undefined is not a function suggests that either

`require('autoprefixer')` doesn't return a function - check if it's installed correctly

OR

`grunt.initConfig` is not a function. When you run this code are you passing grunt in? e.g. `require('gruntfile.js')(grunt)`

I think normally you don't wrap your gruntfile code in a function - the [getting started example](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) doesn't seem to, perhaps unwrap it if you are just running `grunt` from the command line, rather than loading in this config and passing grunt in.